# How can i restore linux backup on virtual machine

Tags: linux, centos, backup-restoration

I have made the backup of my linux OS in `bacukp.tgz` which is `centos 6.4`.
Now i want to create a new virtual machine vmware from it.

So do i first need to install centos form cd or iso and then i overwrite all the files with backup or is there any way i can directly start  with `backup.tgz`

Comment: How did you make it?

Comment: @ALex_hha on Ec2 Live server with tar czpf backup.tgz /

Answer (score 1):

- boot a LiveCD, any Linux Distro is OK.
- partition the disk
- mount your partition (for example to /target)
- mount your other partitions under /target if you plan to have separate /boot, /var, or any other partitions
- copy your backup to /target
- mount /dev, /sys, /proc with bind mount to the /target

  ```
  mount -o bind /dev /target/dev
  mount -o bind /sys /target/sys
  mount -o bind /proc /target/proc
  ```
- chroot into /target

  ```
   chroot /target
  ```
- install grub
- reboot into your restored system

Answer (score 0):

Of course first of all you need to install fresh centos-6.4 and then untar backup.tgz

Answer (score 0):

This started life as a comment but grew too long.

If you untar directly over the system you are running in, it will most likely crash when you overwrite libraries, so you'd need to experiment with excluding various system directories. It would also probably not boot afterwards owing to wrong device paths and missing drivers.

As ALex_hha says, your best plan might be to install a fresh copy of Centos, then selectively restore non-system directories. Or boot your VM off an external iso image, or mount it to another VM, then untar but you'd face the same device problems.

For the future, read up on AWS's VM export, Vmware's Converter, and so-called p2v generally.